# Bloodborne The Old Hunters purchase but no download

Tags: ps4, psn, bloodborne

So on Monday 22/11/2015 I downloaded the 1.07 Bloodborne patch ready for the new DLC. This morning at 00:20 I purchased The Old Hunters addon, I looked around the store after I purchased it and I could not find a download button anywhere, so I thought meh I will go to sleep and sort it out in the morning.

So I check this morning and I still can't see a download button at all in the store, all it displayed is `Purchased`, so I look around and I check my Bloodborne addons. There it displays it has been installed, however I never told it to download and I have no idea on when it downloaded the dlc... Should I trust my PS4 or has anyone else had this issue and knows how to resolve it?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find the Download Button neither.
The Sony PSN Cutomer Service said to me, the Data is already in the 1.07 Patch, there is no Download Button for this DLC.
Then i looked in Hunters Dream for the DLC Item and found it there, so it seems there is no need for a Download Button for this DLC..

Comment: I did think that, to be honest this is probably the right answer :) but I can only confirm once I reach that point and check it

Comment: Yep just to let everyone know, I killed vicar Amelia, got the `Eye of a Blood-Drunk Hunter` from the hunters dream near the doll and then went to cathedral ward where you get the top hat set (suits you sir/madam) got picked up by the monster and got teleported. So yes the The Old Hunters DLC was included in the patch so you don't need to download the DLC from the store you just need to purchase. Praise the sun

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue you faced.

I even follow the process to enable the expansion as per this link http://blog.us.playstation.com/2015/11/20/bloodborne-the-old-hunters-out-tuesday-patch-1-07-detailed/ . Unfortunately, I couldn't complete the process because the Eye of a Blood-drunk Hunter is not found in the Hunter's dream.

I called Sony PSN customer service. They said it's because my CD is Region 2 while the DLC is Region 3 ( per my PSN account). The policy is both must be the same region is order to work. Stupid but that's how things works.

I have asked them to refund my purchase.

Comment: How did you find out what region you have?

Comment: If your PSN account is from Region 3 (aka registered as Region 3), your DLC will be a Region 3 too. As for the CD, you can take a look at the printing on the packaging, it will show R1, R2 or R3. 

Your DLC and your CD must be from the same region for it to work.

.....that's what PSN customer service told me.

FYI. Region 1 is US, Region 2 is Euro/ Japan while 3 is Asia.

What's your finding?

Comment: I can't check at the moment due to being at work :) Will take a look later.

Comment: I have received the refund from PSN....this also means there will be no The old Hunters for me.

How's everything at your end?

Comment: Check out the accepted answer and my comment

Comment: +1 → This *is a valid answer* as the exact same thing happened to me but with two different regions.