# Progress was not transferred from borrowed to owned version of the game

Tags: ps4, horizon-zero-dawn

So, I borrowed Horizon Zero Dawn from a friend and now I'm obsessed with it. I figured I'd get my own, and not continue to use a borrowed copy.

Now, this may be the issue, but I bought my physical copy online from Ozgameshop, based in the UK (I live in Oz and refuse to pay the prices here) and when I popped it in, it started afresh and didn't carry on the progress from my friend's copy.

Is this just what happens when you play a borrowed game and get your own copy? Or is it to do with the fact it is from the UK (I thought they were region free)?

Comment: Im having the same issue. Both my discs used were from the same region, so we can rule that out as the cause. I know others have this problem too!!

Answer (score 6):

While the game is the same, the DRM that locks regions is causing your PS4 to think they are different. Note that any physical disk whatever the region will play in any PS4 from any region. However, they are incompatible as far as the PS4 is concerned. Since your game is UK (aka Region 2), it **is not** compatible with Australia (aka Region 4): thus no save game transfer.

Since you mention the DLC (before it was edited out of the question!):

> **⚠ You will not be able to play any DLCs with your copy of the game!**

Any downloads are for the region where you bought the game. If you have pre-ordered, you should ask for a refund as soon as possible. I had the exact same problem [with bloodborne](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/319422/33618).

Comment: "Note that any physical disk whatever the region will play in any PS4s. The above only refers to DLCs." - is the OP not talking about disks? They talk about borrowing a copy from a friend and then buying their own physical copy. The DLC for Horizon is not yet out so I'm not sure talk of DLC is relevant...

Comment: Except that they are having problems *now* before the DLC. The OPs problem is that their save game doesn't seem to exist any more. While the user may be interested in cross region factors with regards to DLC it is literally impossible that this is the problem he is having now since the game has no DLC currently.

Comment: @Chris Fair 'nuff. I have edited the question to add more emphasis on the first part. Note that I left the DLC elements as they are a side effect of the same problem and it would be a shame if the asker bought something they would not be able to play.

Comment: I don't actually think this is correct, I am playing the Frozen Wilds DLC now, downloaded from the UK PSN store, on an Australian PS4 and Australian physical copy of the original game. This is how I obtain all my DLC's and I have never had an issue.

Comment: @Colin Good for you! I guess that there might be a difference between different regional policies…

Answer (score 4):

Usually for PS4 games, the saved data is on the hard drive and has nothing to do with the disc.

The reason you are having to start over with a new game is probably because your old save is for the non-UK disc and since you are now using a UK based disc, it will not read it(region based).

To confirm this, just get that disc back from your friend and load it up, and see if your old file is still there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll borrow a different copy from another friend and see how that goes!

Answer (score 1):

I got a second hand HZD as a present and I started to play it but I wanted the expansions as well. When the complete edition got discounted on PNS, I got myself a digital copy of it and I'll get rid of the disc version since I prefer digital versions anyway.

As soon as the complete version downloaded I was able to simply continue where I left off in the regular version.

Now, I suspect both versions I have are most probably from the same region, but it worked for me.